# SMTP -> ERROR: AUTH not accepted from server: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. c3sm5545732pax.9 - gsmtp PHPMailer

Tags: phpmailer

i already check if openssl is used by my wamp server and it is check. But what is the problem of my code?

> 

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true); 
$body             = 'THIS IS YOUR USERNAME:'.$row['username'].' PASSWORD: '.$row['password'].'\n PLEASE DELETE THIS MESSAGE AFTER YOU READ THIS';
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
$mail->IsSMTP();                // tell the class to use SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Port       = 587;                    // set the SMTP server port
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tsl'; 
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Username   = "dan.villarea22@gmail.com";     // SMTP server username
$mail->Password   = "password";            // SMTP server password
$mail->AddReplyTo("system@dvts.com","ADMIN");
$mail->From       = "system@dvts.com";
$mail->FromName   = "SYSTEM";
$to = "dan.villareal22@gmail.com";
$mail->AddAddress($to);
$mail->Subject  = "First PHPMailer Message";
$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test
$mail->WordWrap   = 80; // set word wrap
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
$mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML
$mail->Send();echo 'Message has been sent.';
```

Answer (score 8):

Change $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tsl' to $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the host option as follows:

$mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.googlemail.com";

Answer (score 0):

Try using $mail->Port = 465; instead of 587 and check the difference in the below link.
[What is the difference between ports 465 and 587?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796530/what-is-the-difference-between-ports-465-and-587)